# Animating recyclerView items

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm applying some AnimatorSet to the items of a recyclerView,

recyclerView adapter:

```
class MyAdapter(...) : 
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(...)
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    p0.bind(...)
    }


inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View,...) : 
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

fun bind(...) {
        ...
        animateItemView(itemView)
        ...
}
}
}
```

animateItemView function

```
        fun animateItemView(itemView: View) {
        //hide the itemView
        itemView.alpha = 0f

        //moving the itemView down 400f
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView, "translationY", 0f, 400f)
            .apply { duration = 1L }.start()

        //show
        //itemView.alpha = 1f

        //moving the itemView up 400f
        val translateUp = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(itemView, "translationY", 400f, 0f)
            .apply {
                duration = 1000L
                interpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(2f)
            }

        //animating alpha
        val fade = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f)
            .apply {
                addUpdateListener {
                    itemView.alpha = this.animatedValue as Float
                }
                duration = 400L
            }

        //applying
        AnimatorSet().apply { playTogether(translateUp, fade) }.start()


    }
```

result:

[image]

surly when scrolling upwards the `itemView` still slides up, is there a way to apply different animation for scrolling up/down ,, or what is a better approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why everyone is fascinated about putting everything into `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

You can inject this animation into `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` instead as it is aware of exact moment and position where views are added:

```
open class FadeInLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) : super(context, orientation, reverseLayout)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

    private val enterInterpolator = AnticipateOvershootInterpolator(2f)

    override fun addView(child: View, index: Int) {
        super.addView(child, index)
        val h = 400f
        // if index == 0 item is added on top if -1 it's on the bottom
        child.translationY = if(index == 0) -h else h
        // begin animation when view is laid out
        child.alpha = 0.3f
        child.animate().translationY(0f).alpha(1f)
                .setInterpolator(enterInterpolator)
                .setDuration(1000L)
    }
}
```

Then use it as your layout manager:

```
recyclerView.layoutManager = FadeInLinearLayoutManager(context)
```

Comment: for some reason using the index in  `child.translationY = if(index == 0) -h else h` makes the animation very sluggish , I used `itemView.y` to decide if the itemView is in the lower or upper half of the screen, and apply the animation accordingly.
I tried `child.y` in the layoutManager but the values of `child.y` are very weird to me,  sometimes when scrolling up it's negative and other times positive,, I will learn about layoutManager later